# Append the name of each text file to the last line of the file

Tags: 20.04, scripts, text-processing

I have ten files: `firstFile.txt`,...,`tenthFile.txt`

On the last line of the file I would like to append the name of the file.

i.e. for the first one the last line would be `firstFile`

I would like to perform this action in one line of code.

I'm pretty new so not sure what to try, my guess was something like `echo * >> *.txt` but wasn't surprised that didn't work

Comment: `echo * >> *.txt` - bash doesn't implicitly loop over multiple things for you.  One `>>` redirect in one command will only ever open a single file for appending.  And the `echo` command will only run once, with all those args.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One can achieve this by, for example, using a `for` loop, which has the syntax:

```
for var in values; do things; done
```

This code puts the first of the list of *`values`* into *`var`* and performs *`things`* on it, then puts the next value into *`var`* and so on.

We often use this to do the same thing to a bunch of files, as you want to do here.

You can use some suitable expression to get Bash to create a list of your files (the list of values, as I've called it above). Here I suggest you use `*File.txt`. This would be expanded by the shell to a list of all the files in the current directory that end with `File.txt`. So the first bit of your code could be

```
for f in *File.txt; do
```

Instead of `f` you can use some other name for your variable, such as `file`. I suggest using a letter or word in lowercase (there are other variables already defined in the shell with uppercase words, and we don't want to over-ride them). When we call our variable in Bash, we precede its name with `$`. So you would refer to your variable with `$f` or `$file`, and the shell will expand this to the current value of that variable. To prevent further expansions on the result, we almost always use double quotes, so instead of writing `$f`, I would write `"$f"` when I call my variable.

To send some text into a file you can use simple tools like `printf` or `echo` with redirection. You have shown that you know how to use redirection to append content to a file. This: `stuff > file` replaces the contents of *`file`* with *`stuff`* and `stuff >> file` appends *`stuff`* to *`file`*.

We should be really careful with redirection as we can easily overwrite our important files - you won't even get a warning about it. So before you run such a powerful command, you might want to make a backup of your files in another directory, and/or do a dry run where you just check what files are going to be operated on, like this:

```
for f in *File.txt; do echo "$f"; done
```

The above simply returns the list of files that will be acted on.

So let's go back to how you are going to add text to the file. Since we already have the name of the file in our variable, we can use that to generate the text.

Here is how your code could look with `echo`:

```
for f in *File.txt; do echo "$f" >> "$f"; done
```

For `firstFile.txt`, that would run `echo firstFile.txt >> firstFile.txt`, and so on for all the other files matched by `*File.txt`.

But you mentioned that your files end with `.txt` and you don't want that to be in the appended text.

To avoid that you can perform some string manipulation

```
for f in *File.txt; do echo "${f%.*}" >> "$f"; done
```

This `${f%.*}` trims characters from the last `.` character onwards from the string in `$f`, in this case the `.txt`.

You could also use `printf`. It's worth learning as it's more flexible than `echo` and, so I'm told, can be more reliable.

```
for f in *File.txt; do printf '%s\n' "${f%.*}" >> "$f"; done
```

`'%s\n'` is for formatting - `%s` means the text is a string (not a number, for example) and `\n` appends a newline after it (`echo` automatically appends a newline).

Comment: Thank you for this, it is extremely helpful to learn! I may have been implementing it wrong as I get a file called '*File' with every line being *File . do I need to change it to something? And I am using a test dir to do this thanks :)

Comment: @kedoink sorry - I edited my answer - I had not got your filenames right - what you describe happens because `*File` does not match anything. Change it to `*File.txt` or whatever matches your files (the files do need to be in the current directory of course) I also added how to avoid having `.txt` in the appended text.

Comment: @Zanna that might be a good opportunity to mention the bash shell's `nullglob` option. Great answer btw.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zanna that is super helpful, you are brilliant!! Do you know any good resources to help me continue learning?

Comment: @kedoink thank you and you're welcome! You can try http://linuxclass.heinz.cmu.edu/doc/tlcl.pdf - the first part is a very useful intro :)

Comment: Re: `echo` being less "reliable".  If you had a file called `-n.txt`, your echo loop would run `echo "-n" >> "-n.txt"`, and thus not append anything.  There might even be worse things that can happen with some shells / some implementations of echo, but the bash builtin doesn't do anything weird for `echo "-e foo\nbar"`, just outputting it all literally including the `-e`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `find` and `bash`:

```
find <YOUR SEARCH PATH> -type f -exec bash -c 'filepath="{}"; filename=${filepath##*/}; echo ${filename%.*} >> $filepath' \;
```

where

- `<YOUR SEARCH PATH>` - path to a directory with your files
- `-type f` - we are searching for files exactly, not for dirs etc.
- `-exec` - executing bash, where the string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed
- `filepath="{}"`- create **filepath** variable with the current full path file name being processed
- `filename=${filepath##*/}` - create **filename** variable extracting filename from full path
- `echo ${filename%.*} >> $filepath` - strip last dot with an extension from **filename** variable and append name to a file being processed using variable **filepath**

Of course bash command string can be shortened, just tried to explain things better.